# How do I mock static asyc methods in a class with jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have looked through other questions and been looking into how to do this but I am definitely missing something. I have a class that I am looking to mock the return of for testing. The class is used to make api calls easier.

An example is:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class UseApi {
    static async fetchAll(o, callback, errCallback) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${o.baseUrl()}`);
            const res1 = res.data.data.map(el => new o(el.id, el.attributes));
            return callback(res1);
        }
        catch (err) {
            return errCallback(err);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried mocking it a few different ways but most of the time I get an unhandled promise rejection error and code coverage shows it not making it very far.

I would ideally like to set something up where i can pass it the value that each of my calls should return so that I can easily reuse this in testing.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do something like this:

```js
import UseApi from './UseApi';

const response = { success: true, data: [] }; // Response example
UseApi.constructor.run = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(response));
```

Comment: Still isn't continuing with the code. Doesn't seem to be using the callback function with the return data.